# Show ReSharper warnings in the Error list window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I am trying to show ReSharper warnings inside of the Visual Studio “Error list” window, but it seems that only errors are shown inside of the window. Is there a way to show ReSharper warnings inside of the “Error list” window in vanilla ReSharper?

Example:

```
if (1 == 1) ;
```

This code generates two warnings:

- A visual studio warning: `CS0642 Possible mistaken empty statement`
- And a resharper warning: `Similar expression comparison`

But the “Error list” window just shows the Visual Studio one.

[image]

Notes:

- I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 - Update 1 and ReSharper 10.0.2.
- I know that I can change the inspection severity to *error* but that is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how to put R# quick-fixes (such as `Similar expression comparison`) into this Visual Studio Error List window.

However, R# has its own "error list". Try `ReSharper -> Inspect -> Code issues in Solution` and you'll get the same functionality and even better.

And yes, R# Inspection Results will contain both `Possible mistaken empty statement` and `Similar expression comparison` messages:
[image]

Comment: I followed this but it only shows c# warnings. How do I configure it so it shows javascript warnings as well?

Comment: @HanmingZeng have you enabled Javascript support in R# `Options -> Environment -> Products and Features`? I checked in R# 2016.3 and I got  JS warnings here.